# Geoplugin interaction from contact page

Tags: geo

I register the client domain from my personal gmail account to test the feature of geoplugin.
As it need premuium subscription to have unlimited rate limits,
When I tried to add same domain from client account, it says domain already registered.
I have send geoplugin team many email from their contact page, but haven't heard from them.

Has anyone interacted with them via their contact page or any other medium where I can contact them.
Hope to get your experience on this.

Thank you.

Hi everyone,
I register the client domain from my personal gmail account to test the feature of geoplugin.
As it need premuium subscription to have unlimited rate limits,
When I tried to add same domain from client account, it says domain already registered.
I have send geoplugin team many email from their contact page, but haven't heard from them.

Has anyone interacted with them via their contact page or any other medium where I can contact them.
Hope to get your experience on this.

Thank you.